# Logging out the user when token has expired - react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-boilerplate

I'm just wondering what approach you guys have taken to implement the functionality of logging out a user when the token has expired and a 401 unauthorized response is received from the backend.currently i am using the axios interceptor.

Comment: block the UI (using a global state( and show a modal like "You are logged out"

Answer (score -1):

hmmmmm. u never showed us any code to help in the answer to this question , 
but , in my application i made use of the `setTimeout(()=>{}, 60000)` function after a successful log in , i set the time out to the exact time the cookie will expire and an action is dipatched when that time is reached .. so i dipatch a logOut action and set the user details in the store to the initial state which is null and redirect the user to the login page .. its that simple  maybe this little code might help

i put this method in the App.js component or the root component the application feeds from where auth.id is the authenticated users id

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps.auth.id !== this.props.auth.id) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.props.onLogoOut(nextProps.auth.id) //passing the user id
                }, 60000) //one minute 

        }
    }
```

hope its clear enough